# isAuthenticated() false for first time AJAX request

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

**Basic information**

I've been googling and searching the web for an answer, but I could not find an answer to my problem. I'm using NodeJS with ExpressJS and Passport.js for the user authentication. The login form is sent via AJAX to /api/auth/login. I'm using PassportJS in combination with Passport-local, and for the session storage I use express-session with MySQLStorage and cookie-parser for the cookies. I've tried to change the order of the express-session and storage, and tried to change the redirect method. But that didn't help...

**The problem**

When the user is logged in, he's redirected to the dashboard (/). You're only allowed to see the dashboard if `req.isAuthenticated() === true`. That's working fine, but on the dashboard, when the whole page is loaded, it does an AJAX GET request for some graph data. But then `req.isAuthenticated()` is false, sometimes...

It happens random, and only after logging in. When I refresh the dashboard page, the authentication is successful and it doesn't happen anymore when you're logged in. So only **sometimes** after logging in. It's not consistent.

**Files**

*/route.js (The express configuration)*

```
let sessionStore = new MySQLStore({ schema: { tableName: "n_sessions", columnNames: { session_id: "session_id", expires: "expires", data: "data" } } }, connection);
app.use(session({
  secret: "Secret",
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  cookie : { secure : false, maxAge : (4 * 60 * 60 * 1000) },
  store: sessionStore
}));

app.enable("trust proxy");
app.set("trust proxy", "loopback");

app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.set("views", __dirname + "/views");
app.use("/assets", express.static(__dirname + "/assets", { maxAge: 86400 }));
app.use(helmet());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: "50mb"}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  limit: "50mb",
  extended: true
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(flash());
```

*/api/auth.js (API route for 'auth')*

```
router.post("/login", bruteforce.prevent, csrfProtection, function(req, res, next) {

  auth.loginAsync(req, res, next).then(function(data) {
    req.brute.reset();
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.send(data);
  }).catch(function(err) {
    res.send(err);
  });

});
```

*Passport.js*

```
var Promise = require("bluebird");
var mysql = require("./mysql");
var users = require("../models/user");

const connection = Promise.promisifyAll(mysql);
var passportTemplate = {};

var passport = require("passport");
var LocalStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy;

passportTemplate.passport = passport;
passportTemplate.LocalStrategy = LocalStrategy;

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  users.loginUserAsync(id).then(function(data) {
    done(null, data);
  }).error(function(err) {
    done(JSON.stringify(err), false);
  });
});

passport.use("local-login", new LocalStrategy({
  usernameField: "username",
  passwordField: "password",
  passReqToCallback: true,
  enableProof: true
}, function(req, username, password, done) {

  connection.queryAsync("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? AND inactive = 0", [username]).then(function(rows) {

    if(!rows.length) {
      return done(null, false, { message: "Invalid username and/or password" });
    } else if(!(users.validPassword(password, rows[0].password))) {
      return done(null, false, { message: "Invalid username and/or password" });
    } else {
      if(req.body.rememberMe) {
        req.session.cookie.maxAge = 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
      } else {
        req.session.cookie.expires = false;
      }
      return done(null, rows[0]);
    }

  }).error(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
    return done(null, false, {message: "MySQL Error"});
  })
}));

module.exports = passportTemplate;
```

*AJAX POST for login*

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/api/auth/login",
    type: "POST",
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
      response({"error": XMLHttpRequest.status, "error_description": XMLHttpRequest.statusText})
    },
    success: function(result) {
        if(result.error) {
            $('#mesAlertText').text(err.error_description);
            $('#mesAlert').show();
        } else {
            window.location.href = '/';
        }
    }
})
```

*AJAX GET for graph*

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/api/devices/sessions/overall/year/",
    type: "get",
    xhrFields: { withCredentials: true },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
      response({'error': XMLHttpRequest.status, 'error_description': XMLHttpRequest.statusText})
    },
    success: function(result) {
        if(result.error) {
            $('#yearly_action').show();
            $('#yearly_action').html('<i class="fa fa-close"></i><br />Error loading yearly charts, please try again');
        } else {
            $('#yearly_action').hide();
            $('#yearly_chart').attr('style', '');
            sessionsYearlyChart.data.datasets[0].data = [];
            Object.keys(response.summary).forEach(function(data) { sessionsYearlyChart.data.datasets[0].data.push(response.summary[data].count); })
            sessionsYearlyChart.update();
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: i don't quite get what your problem is but you are not passing the Localstrategy as a middleware to the router.post("/login").

Comment: @PaoloMangia when I add the LocalStrategy to the middleware of router.post("/login"), the request gets stuck.